# How to create a query with a lot of parameters in hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate

I'm trying to create a query that can receive a lot of parameters (30 - 35) and they all gonna be a `from / to` like this:

```
select * from sales where sale_date > date_from  and sale_date < date_to;
```

Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can shorten the query with between expression

```
select * from sales where sale_date between date_from and date_to;
```

And if you want to do it in code you can use the [Criteria API](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html)

Comment: That is not the same query. `between` is equivalent to `sale_date >= date_from and sale_date <= date_to` whereas the question contains `>` and `<`